# Is it possible to assign to a regular variable and slice in the same statement?

Tags: go, variables

I'm making a chess game and I want to do a series of type assertions in the same `var` statement, then pass them to a function that handles it, but apparently, Go doesn't allow me to assign to a regular variable and a slice index in the same statement:

```golang
// inside a function:
asserts := make([]bool, 0, 10)
assertionHandler := func(ok *[]bool) {
    for _, b := range *ok {
        if !b {
            msg := "pieceCliked: failed while trying to do type assertion\n%s\n\n"
            utils.LogPrintError(errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(msg, string(debug.Stack()))))
        }
    }
    *ok = make([]bool, 0, 10)
}

var (
    possibleSquares []string
    // The following results in a syntax error: expected type, found '='
    dataObject, asserts[0]  = data.(map[string]any) 
    playerData, asserts[1]  = dataObject["playerData"].(map[string]any)
    square, asserts[2]      = playerData["selectedPieceLocation"].(string)
    piece, asserts[3]       = playerData["selectedPiece"].(string)
    color, asserts[4]       = playerData["selectedPieceColor"].(string)
)
assertionHandler(asserts)
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the way you're doing it, no. A `var` block defines new variables and their types, but you're trying to assign to both new variables with no types (hence the error `expected type`) and elements of an existing slice within that block.

You could do:

```
var (
    possibleSquares []string
    dataObject map[string]any
    playerData map[string]any
    square string
    piece string
    color string
)

dataObject, asserts[0]  = data.(map[string]any) 
playerData, asserts[1]  = dataObject["playerData"].(map[string]any)
square, asserts[2]      = playerData["selectedPieceLocation"].(string)
piece, asserts[3]       = playerData["selectedPiece"].(string)
color, asserts[4]       = playerData["selectedPieceColor"].(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer describes why the code in the question does not work.  Here's another workaround:

Write assertion handler to use variadic argument:

```
func assertionHandler(asserts ...bool) bool {
    result := true
    for _, b := range assserts {
        if !b {
            result = false
            msg := "pieceCliked: failed while trying to do type assertion\n%s\n\n"
            utils.LogPrintError(errors.New(fmt.Sprintf(msg, string(debug.Stack()))))
        }
    }   
    return result
}
```

Use short variable declarations to collect the values and bool results:

```
dataObject, assert0 := data.(map[string]any) 
playerData, assert1 := dataObject["playerData"].(map[string]any)
square, assert2     := playerData["selectedPieceLocation"].(string)
piece, assert3      := playerData["selectedPiece"].(string)
color, assert4      := playerData["selectedPieceColor"].(string)
if !assertionHandler(assert0, assert1, assert2, assert3, assert4) {
   return
}
```

Comment: I thought about what you're saying before, but I'm running the game's logic on a web server, and I don't want the server to terminate because of something like a type assertion.

Comment: I still like the slice idea, but had not thought about returning on fail. I'll do it.

Comment: After some minutes I realized that I was over-engineering the problem. I'll do what you proposed.